Trying to create a new dataframe based on group by calculation on an existing dataframe in Python
I have an 18,000 record dataset in the below format:



Date
Tm
Site
Opp
Player
Dist
Made
Blocked
GameID
Season




2024-01-07
ARI
H
SEA
Matt Prater
51
N
N
SEA @ ARI
2023


2024-01-07
DAL
A
WAS
Brandon Aubrey
50
Y
N
DAL @ WAS
2023


2024-01-07
TAM
A
CAR
Chase McLaughlin
57
Y
N
TAM @ CAR
2023


2024-01-07
CAR
H
TAM
Matthew Wright
52
N
N
TAM @ CAR
2023


2024-01-07
CHI
A
GNB
Cairo Santos
50
Y
N
CHI @ GNB
2023



There is data for 50 seasons. My goal for this part of my project is to calculate the number of attempts (each line is one attempt) per game (unique GameID) by season. My thought was the best route is to create a dataframe that has columns for season, attempts, games, and average per game.
I've run a calculation for attempts by using:
df.groupby(['Season']).size()

And unique games by using:
df.groupby('Season')['GameID'].nunique()

Each of these brings back a table by year, so I was thinking that I could create a dictionary with the three fields to build a new dataframe.
data = {"Year":df.groupby(['Season']), "FG":df.groupby(['Season']).size(), "Games":df.groupby('Season')['GameID'].nunique()}
dfgrp = pd.DataFrame(data)

But I get a very long error when I try to view dfgrp, where it stops iteration but doesn't identify what the issue is.
I've tried looking through multiple searches but there doesn't seem to be a matching question that addresses this issue. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do. Something like this? out = df.groupby(['Season'], as_index=False).agg(FG=('Season', 'size'), Games=('GameID', 'nunique')) if you add what you expect the output to be, it would be easier to help

I am also not sure what you want to do. Why don't you groupby(by=['Season', 'GameID']).nunique()? From your post I assume that you need information about each GameID in the season, which are lost using .agg().

You could skip a few steps with pd.groupby.agg().
df.groupby('Season').agg(size=('Season', 'size'),
                         nunique=('GameID', 'nunique'))

        size    nunique
Season      
  2023     5          4


Your idea is better than mine.  Much appreciated
